# using os.walk method to get directory paths containing 2 types of files

Tags: python, python-2.7, os.walk

I want to list all folders containing `docx` files using `os()`.walk method in Python 2.7. I managed to do that with code written below, but I want to know if it is possible to limit this list to show only folders containing exactly two specific file types (for example "docx" and "pdf")?

```
import os
import walk

a = open("output.txt", "w")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(('.docx')):
            f = os.path.join(path, filename)
            a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just skip directories where you don't have at least those two extensions; per-directory file lists are limited so it's cheap to use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) to test for specific extensions:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop'):
    if not (any(f.endswith('.pdf') for f in files) and 
            any(f.endswith('.docx') for f in files)):
        # no PDF or Word files here, skip
        continue
    # directory contains *both* PDF and Word documets
```

When the list of extensions to test for gets a bit longer, you may want to just create a set of all available extensions:

```
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop'):
    extensions = {os.path.splitext(f)[-1] for f in files}
    if not extensions >= {'.pdf', '.docx', '.odt', '.wpf'}:
        # directory doesn't contain *all* required file types 
        continue
```

`>=` tests if the right-hand set is a subset of the left (so `extensions` is a [superset of the right-hand set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.issuperset)); so `extensions` should *at least* contain all for extensions named on the right:

```
>>> {'.foo', '.docx', '.pdf', '.odt'} >= {'.pdf', '.docx', '.odt', '.wpf'}  # missing .wpf
False
>>> {'.foo', '.wpf', '.docx', '.pdf', '.odt'} >= {'.pdf', '.docx', '.odt', '.wpf'} # complete
True
```

Comment: can I add condition that docx and pdf files must start with a digit using isdigit method?

Comment: @stjepan: sure you can. `f[0].isdigit()` would test if there is a first character is a digit. You may need to rework all your tests to cover multiple aspects.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
import os

a = open("output.txt", "w")
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\Stephen\Desktop'):
    docx = False
    pdf = False
    rest = True
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith(('.docx')):
            docx = True
        elif filename.endswith(('.pdf')):
            pdf = True
        else:
            rest = False
            break
    if docx and pdf and rest:
        f = os.path.join(path, filename)
        a.write(str(f) + os.linesep)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked too. I had to remove ", filename" from f = os.path.join(path, filename) to get only path.